# Is it possibile to reorder jform control-group with jquery?

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

First of all I'm not sure if this counts as Joomla question or jQuery question. I have manipulated the joomla user jform and added an extra field jform_firstname to the list of fields. The current output is:

```
<div id="details">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">
            <label id="jform_username-lbl" for="jform_username" class="hasPopover required" title="" data-content="Enter the login name (Username) for the user." data-original-title="Login Name">
                Login Name<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="jform[username]" id="jform_username" value="james" class="required" size="30" required="required" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">
            <label id="jform_password-lbl" for="jform_password" class="hasPopover" title="" data-content="Enter the password for the user." data-original-title="Password">
                Password
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" name="jform[password]" id="jform_password" value="" autocomplete="off" class="validate-password" size="30" maxlength="99">                       
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">
            <label id="jform_email-lbl" for="jform_email" class="hasPopover required" title="" data-content="Enter an email address for the user." data-original-title="Email">
                Email<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" name="jform[email]" class="validate-email required" id="jform_email" value="admin@deanimaconsulting.com" size="30" required="required" aria-required="true">                        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">
            <label id="jform_firstname-lbl" for="jform_firstname" class="required">
                First name<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="jform[firstname]" id="jform_firstname" value="James" class="required" size="30" maxlength="255" required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible with jQuery to move the whole control-group which contains jform_firstname to after the control-group for jform-username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with something like this

```
jQuery('.control-group').has('#jform_firstname')
    .insertAfter(jQuery('.control-group').has('#jform_username'));
```